# uses XmlHttpRequest asynchronously for server requests, how many maximum simultaneous requests would be possible

Tags: xmlhttprequest, python-requests

```
function startAR()
{
for (var a = 0; a < 100; a++){
executeAR();
}
};
```

And considering that executeAR() uses XmlHttpRequest asynchronously for server requests, how many
maximum simultaneous requests would be possible in this cycle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to determinate and calculate the XmlHttpRequest. Use your google chrome console (navigate to Network) to see that the requests will be 100 times.

```js
function loadXMLDoc() {
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "xmlhttp_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest object</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```